# How to add (not append) a 2d array to each 2d array of a 3d array?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to vectorize the process of adding a 2d array to every 2d array inside a 3d array.

I imported an image file using image from matplotlib

```
data = image.imread('test.jpg')
```

Then I tried to add the average of each RGB array to another array of the same shape as `data`

```
data2 = np.zeros_like(data)
data3 = np.average(data, axis=2)
for i in range(len(data2[0,0,:])):
    data2[:,:,i] = data3
```

I just want to vectorize the above 2 line code to one line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `data3` to the result datatype and then broadcast/repeat after extending to `3D` with [`np.newaxis/None`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) -

```
b = data3.astype(data.dtype)
data2_out = np.broadcast_to(b[...,None], data.shape)
```

The output would simply be a view into `b` and hence we are gaining memory-efficiency there.

If you need an output with its own memory space, we can force the copy with `data2_out.copy()` or use `np.repeat`, like so -

```
np.repeat(b[...,None],data.shape[2],axis=2)
```

If you already have the output array `data2` initialized and just want to assign into it, we can do so with extending `data3` to `3D` and this might more intuitive in some scenarios too, like so -

```
data2[:] = data3[...,None]
```

Comment: Thanks that did the job

Comment: What does the [...,None] indexing mean? 
Or can you link the docs which explain this type of indexing.

Comment: @PrashantGaikwad Added.

Comment: Oh sorry, I am new here so I didn't know I needed to do that.